# file_get_contents() in php not working

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I am using file_get_contents() in php that is not working when i am
using like this. the file name is index.php

```
<?php
    $content = "hi";
    $content = file_get_contents('index.php');
    echo $content;
?>
```

I thought it prints hi more than one tym.. but it print that only one
 time.. why? tell me please...

Comment: What does `index.php` contain?

Answer (score 4):

I think what you're trying to do here, is first give a value to `$content`, and then *add* whatever is in `index.php`.

If that's the case, do this:

```
<?php
$content  = "hi";
$content .= file_get_contents('index.php');
echo $content;
?>
```

With `=` you *redefine* a variable, so it doesn't matter what it was before.
With `.=` you *add* something to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : check path & access rights.

From your codes, your variable **$content** is overwritten by the result returned by `file_get_contents()` . Therefore, your echo is printing our the result returned by the function.

p.s. the function should work. Read the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php).

Answer (score 0):

I think you’re trying to use recursion here. If you view source it probably says,

```
hi<?php
    $content = "hi";
    $content .= file_get_contents('index.php');
    echo $content;
?>
```

The reason it is only printing “hi” is because your browser doesn't recognize the `<php` tag as valid HTML so it ignores it.

If my assumption is correct, then my question is *Why do you want to do this? What are you trying to accomplish?*

Comment: actually, that `<?php` tag **is** valid. You are probably thinking of headers being sent prematurely, but that's a problem for another context.

Comment: @chelmertz The point I was trying to make is that it's not **HTML** so the browser doesn't display it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't follow you. Why would `<?php` be considered html? OP stated that the script does print "hi" once, thus he must be entering php correctly.

Comment: @chelmertz: The **server** processes the PHP and assigns "Hi" to `$content`. Then it reads the PHP file as a _string_ and appends it to `$content`. Thus the full string (including all the text within the PHP tag) is sent to the browser. The **browser** sees `<?php...?>` as a single empty tag (which the **browser** doesn't recognize) so it ignores it. Put the code in a file called 'index.php', run it, and view source. It'll show "Hi" in the browser window, but the _source_ will contain the string in my answer.

Comment: "Put the code in a file called 'index.php'" <-- that's where I lost you I think. I follow the rest of your points, but we don't know OPs code is itself in index.php ;) Nvm, let's stop wasting our time here.

Comment: OP says in the 1st sentence "the file name is index.php".